# clear string from signs which cant be used in filename

Tags: c#

Im generating various strings and then I want to save files with generated strings as filenames. Sometimes generated string has got various chars which arent allowed to use in filename.

Is there any ready to use class or sth which can clean up string from such characters ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at

[Path.GetInvalidPathChars()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars.aspx) and [Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can can the list of invalid characters from the `Path` class - specifically the [`GetInvalidFileNameChars`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars.aspx) and [`GetInvalidPathChars`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars.aspx) methods.

You can use these in conjunction with the different `string` methods to cleanup the string.